# Can datastax driver load data from cell/column not in table schema?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, dynamic-columns

The table I am having trouble with does have a schema. At some time point we started writing to a "dynamic" column (which is not in schema) for each insert, by using Netflix' astyanax driver - as it uses thrift API and supports such operation easily.

Now we want to migrate to datastax driver. But I couldn't figure out how to read that "dynamic" column. We use the mapping mechanism provided by datastax driver and an "undefined" column cannot be mapped.

I see one option is to alter the table and add that "dynamic" column to schema. However I am not sure **how expensive** this operation is as the table already contains hundreds of millions of rows.

Besides altering table schema, is there a way to read that column with datastax driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns in Cassandra are only metadata, so adding new columns is quick and cheap even if there are billions of rows.

I recommend bringing those "dynamic" columns into your schema. After that, you could rethink your schema to reflect the real meaning of those "dynamic" columns (for example by creating collection columns or user defined types).

Comment: Good - I also thought adding the column to schema is the best solution. Good to know it's a very lightweight operation. Thanks!